# Регулярные выражения в bash скрипте

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Нужно переместить из каталога А в каталог В файлы, у которых в названии больше трех цифр.
Код bash скрипта:

```
#!/bin/bash
mv ./cat1/* cat2
```

Этот код позволяет переместить файлы из каталога 1 в каталог 2, но как добавить регулярное выражение в этот код, пытался по-всякому и через grep, но ничего не выходит. Может кто знает?

Comment: я бы попробовал где то так `mv ./cat1/*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]* cat2`

Comment: спасибо. работает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Где то так `mv ./cat1/*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]* cat2`. Как  это работает - ищем файлы, в котором есть какие то символы (`*`), потом цифра `[0-9]`)  и так до нужного кол-ва символов. Звездочка может соответствовать как отсутствию сиволов, так и цифрам. Так как явно написано 4 цифры, то и будет выбирать файлы, в которых есть как минимум 4 цифры (то есть, больше 3 цифр).